# ListView ArrayAdapter didn't get any data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an app that is show data in a ListView from SQLite database

i didn't get any exception and etc but my data doesn't show

here is my Activity code

```
    package id.habatus.amsw;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SyncCollectActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private CollectDataHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView list;
    private List<SyncCollect> syncs;
    Cursor cursor;

    public static final int NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 1;
    public static final int NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 0;
    public static final String DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST = "id.habatus.datasaved";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private SyncCollectAdapter adapter;
    Button col, drop;
    ImageButton back;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync_collect);
        dbHelper = new CollectDataHelper(this);
        syncs = new ArrayList<>();

        list = findViewById(R.id.listViewNames);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        drop = findViewById(R.id.btncanvas);
        back = findViewById(R.id.kembali);
        loadData();
        refresh();
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                //loading the names again
                loadData();
                refresh();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));


        drop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SyncCollectActivity.this,SyncActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SyncCollectActivity.this,DecisionActivity.class);
            }
        });


    }

    private void loadData() {
        syncs.clear();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                SyncCollect sync = new SyncCollect(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.id_p)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.nama)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.alamat)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.saldo)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.pinjaman)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.angsuran)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.keterangan)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.latitude)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.longitude)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.status)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.syncstatus))

                );
                syncs.add(sync);
            }
        }
        adapter = new SyncCollectAdapter(this,R.layout.sync_item,syncs);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void refresh(){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
}
```

in this activity i want to show all data from my SQLite database, i am suspecting that on the method loadData there's something wrong but maybe it's wrong. 
this is my CollectDataHelper class

```
    package id.habatus.amsw;

/**
 * Created by SMK TELKOM on 9/6/2018.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


    public class CollectDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
    public static  final String id_p = "id_p";
    public static  final String nama = "nama";
    public static  final String alamat = "alamat";
    public static  final String saldo = "saldo";
    public static  final String pinjaman = "pinjaman";
    public static  final String angsuran = "angsuran";
    public static  final String keterangan = "keterangan";
    public static  final String latitude = "latitude";
    public static  final String longitude = "longitude";
    public static  final String syncstatus = "syncstatus";
    public static final String status = "status";
    public static  final String table = "collect";
    String TAG = "C_DL Activity";

    public static  final String broadcast = "id.habatus.amsw.broadcast";
    public static final  int SYNC_STATUS_OK = 1;
    public static final  int SYNC_STATUS_FAILED = 0;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "col";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String  DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS collect";
    public CollectDataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "create table collect(id_p integer primary key, nama text null, alamat text null, saldo text null, pinjaman text null, angsuran text null, keterangan text null, latitude text null, longitude text null,status text null, syncstatus integer);";
        Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO collect (`id_p`, `nama`, `alamat`, `saldo`, `pinjaman`, `angsuran`, `keterangan`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `status`, `syncstatus`) VALUES\n" +
                "(909095, 'AM Nata Waskita', 'Kediri', '0', '500000', '65000', 'segera', '-7.2583968', '112.7109815','NOTCOLL', '0');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getList(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT rowid as " +KEY_ROWID+ "," +id_p+ "," +nama+ "," +alamat+ "," +saldo+ "," +pinjaman+ "," +angsuran+
                "," +keterangan+ " FROM " + table;

        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor == null){
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return  cursor;
    }
    public Cursor getListByKeyword(String search){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT rowid as "+KEY_ROWID+ "," +id_p+","+nama+ ","+alamat+","+saldo+","+pinjaman+","+angsuran+
                ","+keterangan+" FROM " + table + " WHERE " + nama + "  LIKE  '%" +search+ "%' " ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null );

        if(cursor == null){
            return null;
        }else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllData() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(id_p, cursor.getString(0));
                map.put(nama, cursor.getString(1));
                map.put(alamat, cursor.getString(2));
                map.put(saldo, cursor.getString(3));
                map.put(pinjaman, cursor.getString(4));
                map.put(angsuran, cursor.getString(5));
                map.put(keterangan, cursor.getString(6));
                map.put(latitude, cursor.getString(7));
                map.put(longitude, cursor.getString(8));
                map.put(status, cursor.getString(9));
                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.e("select sqlite ", "" + wordList);

        database.close();
        return wordList;
    }

    public boolean edit(String id_p, String nama, String alamat, String saldo, String pinjaman, String angsuran, String keterangan,String latitude,
                        String longitude, String status,int syncstatus){
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.nama,nama);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.alamat,alamat);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.saldo,saldo);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.pinjaman,pinjaman);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.angsuran,angsuran);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.keterangan,keterangan);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.latitude,latitude);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.longitude,longitude);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.status,status);
            cv.put(CollectDataHelper.syncstatus, syncstatus);
            int result = db.update(table,cv, CollectDataHelper.id_p + " =?",new String[]{id_p});
            if (result > 0){
                return true;
            }

        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    public  boolean updatelocal(String id_p , int syncstatus){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DataHelper.syncstatus,syncstatus);

        database.update(DataHelper.table,contentValues, CollectDataHelper.id_p + "=" + id_p,null);
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getUnsynced(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE "+ syncstatus + " = 0";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        return c;
    }
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " ORDER BY " + id_p + " ASC;";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return c;
    }


}
```

in the method getData i want to select all my data from collect table and order by it's id, i tried the query on the SQLite query executor on a website and it's working properly.

this is my adapter class

```
    package id.habatus.amsw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by SMK TELKOM on 9/20/2018.
 */

public class SyncCollectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SyncCollect> {
    private List<SyncCollect> SyncCollects;
    private Context context;

    public SyncCollectAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<SyncCollect> SyncCollects) {
        super(context, resource, SyncCollects);
        this.context = context;
        this.SyncCollects = SyncCollects;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //getting the layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //getting listview itmes
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_item2, null, true);
        TextView txid = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txid_p);
        TextView txnama = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txname);
        TextView txalamat = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txalamat);
        TextView txsaldo = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txsaldo);
        TextView txpinjaman = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txpinjaman);
        TextView txangsuran = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txangsuran);
        TextView txketerangan = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txketerangan);
        TextView txlatitude = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txlatitude);
        TextView txlongitude = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txlongitude);
        TextView txstatus = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txstatus);
        ImageView status = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imsync);

        //getting the current name
        SyncCollect name = SyncCollects.get(position);

        //setting the name to textview
        txid.setText(name.getId_p());
        txnama.setText(name.getNama());
        txalamat.setText(name.getAlamat());
        txsaldo.setText(name.getSaldo());
        txpinjaman.setText(name.getPinjaman());
        txangsuran.setText(name.getAngsuran());
        txketerangan.setText(name.getKeterangan());
        txlatitude.setText(name.getLatitude());
        txlongitude.setText(name.getLongitude());
        txstatus.setText(name.getStatus());


        //if the SyncCollected status is 0 displaying
        //queued icon
        //else displaying SyncCollected icon
        if (name.getSyncstatus() == 0)
            status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refresh);
        else
            status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

i think that there's nothing wrong with this class because i make it as much as my columns on database but i just leave this here in case you need it

and this is my SyncCollect Class

```
    public class SyncCollect {

    public String nama;
    public String id_p;
    public int syncstatus;
    public String saldo;
    public String alamat;
    public String pinjaman;
    public String angsuran;
    public String keterangan;
    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;
    public String status;



    public SyncCollect(String id_p, String nama, String alamat, String pinjaman, String angsuran, String keterangan, String saldo, String latitude, String longitude,String status, int syncstatus) {
        this.id_p = id_p;
        this.nama = nama;
        this.alamat = alamat;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.pinjaman = pinjaman;
        this.angsuran = angsuran;
        this.keterangan = keterangan;
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;
        this.status = status;
        this.syncstatus=syncstatus;

    }
    public int getSyncstatus() {
        return syncstatus;
    }

    public void setSyncstatus(int syncstatus) {
        this.syncstatus = syncstatus;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getId_p() {
        return id_p;
    }

    public void setId_p(String id_p) {
        this.id_p = id_p;
    }

    public String getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(String saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public String getAlamat() {
        return alamat;
    }

    public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
        this.alamat = alamat;
    }

    public String getPinjaman() {
        return pinjaman;
    }

    public void setPinjaman(String pinjaman) {
        this.pinjaman = pinjaman;
    }

    public String getAngsuran() {
        return angsuran;
    }

    public void setAngsuran(String angsuran) {
        this.angsuran = angsuran;
    }

    public String getKeterangan() {
        return keterangan;
    }

    public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
        this.keterangan = keterangan;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void  setStatus(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

i think there's nothing wrong here too because it's parameter is the same as my columns on database.

i have search everything related to this but there's no solution for this problem, i hope anyone can help me.

Thank You Very Much

Comment: Make sure overriding `getCount` method

Comment: i've already overriding getCount and nothing happened @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue may be due to the table only having a single row (according to the insert in the onCreate method of the CollectDataHelper class).

That is, assuming that the row is inserted and no other rows are inserted then.

The **movetoFirst** will move to the first (only) row it is then followed by a **moveToNext** which is then after the last row (or at the 2nd row if multiple rows, so skipping the first row) so false is returned an the while loop isn't entered. Therefore no data to display, no error either.

Perhaps the solution is to use :-

```
private void loadData() {
    syncs.clear();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        SyncCollect sync = new SyncCollect(
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.id_p)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.nama)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.alamat)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.saldo)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.pinjaman)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.angsuran)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.keterangan)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.latitude)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.longitude)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.status)),
            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CollectDataHelper.syncstatus))
        );
        syncs.add(sync);
    }
```

- Even if the table contains more rows, the first row would be skipped without the above change.